# BUTTON ONCLICK ONSERVERCLICK

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick

I am facing a problem with buttons.

I want a client side validation to occur(say selecting a maximum of only 4 checkboxes in a datalist).

I used a INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" RUNAT="SERVER" style of tag. and put Onserverclick="someservermethod" which works fine.

I wrote a Validate() and added onclick="return validate();" to the above HTML markup and was thinking if it returns false then my server side code someservermethod() would not execute and it works great as expected

But when I return true I thought it would fire my someservermethod(),  but it is not working. Any thoughts on why it is not working?

HTML MARKUP BELOW FOR THE BUTTON

```
button onclick="return ValidateSelection();" type="button" id="btnSubmit"
                runat="server" onserverclick="btnSubmit_Click"
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function ValidateSelection()
{
  if(good)
  {
    // I expect that my server side code btn_Submit would have got called. But
    // it doesn't get called.
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    //This works great. Not calling the server side method for the button
    alert('something happened');
    return false;
  }  
}
```

I think I am messing up with the formatting. Pardon me.

Comment: Show us complete input tag along with javascript mathod for validation

Comment: So the actual problem is that your client side `validate()` function returns true but the server side code is not executed? If so, do you have any form submission at all?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In my case the .aspx doesnot have any form submission tags. But earlier when I was not supposed to validate, I just had onserverclick. Now I need to do clientside validation and then after googling for sometime I added the Validate() and called it from the button's onclick.

Comment: Sounds like you are overwriting the click event in a wrong way. Try with such button instead: `<asp:button OnClientClick="return ValidateSelection();" id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>`

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. I see what u r saying. Actually this is the answer too for my questions. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Cheers, added it as answer then so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control you are using right now it HtmlButton which is not "fit" for what you are trying to do, as your `onclick` overwrites the required client side code for the post back.

What you need is the Button control which does support overwriting the client side `onclick` and still perform the post back as usual.

Change the markup to this and it should work:

```
<asp:button OnClientClick="return ValidateSelection();" id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
```